# Sed capture group

Tags: regex, sed

I have a problem with `sed` unable to correctly capture the `\1` capture group in the below example:

```
echo '//apple' | sed "s/^\(\/\)\{0,2\}apple\(\/\)\?/\1banana\2/"
                         -------------              --
                            ^                        ^
                            |                        |__ writing back what it captured
                            |
                            |_ this is the capture group that I have problem capturing
```

I expected the output of: `//banana` correctly capturing the `//`. How can I make `sed` to correctly the `\1` capture group?

Comment: You only captured one `/`

Comment: With alternate delimiter use cleaner sed: `sed -E 's~(/{0,2})apple(/{0,2})~\1banana\2~'`

Answer (score 2):

You only captured one `/`.

You need to use

```sh
echo '//apple' | sed 's/^\(\/\{0,2\}\)apple\(\/\)\?/\1banana\2/' # POSIX BRE
echo '//apple' | sed -E 's~^(/{0,2})apple(/)?~\1banana\2~'       # POSIX ERE variant
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/3ecwEU). The POSIX BRE pattern matches

- `^` - start of string
- `\(\/\{0,2\}\)` - Group 1: zero, one or two occurrences of a `/` char
- `apple` - a fixed string
- `\(\/\)\?`  - an optional Group 2 matchong a `/` char.

Note you do not need to escape capturing parentheses, nor `?` and `{min,max}` quantifiers when using POSIX ERE regex that is enabled with the `-E` option.

You need not escape `/` chars in the sed command when `/` is not used as a regex delimiter char.

Also, see [this regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%2F%7B0%2C2%7D)apple(%2F)%3F):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the tip on `-E` I will use this option from now on.

Answer (score 1):

With an alternate delimiter and `-E` use cleaner and easier to read:

```
echo '//apple' | sed -E 's~^(/{0,2})apple(/{0,2})~\1banana\2~'
```

Comment: Thanks. But yours is missing the needed `^`, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: If option -E is not working, try to use -r instead.
Furthermore:
I think your sed statemet could be shortened to `sed 's|\w\+|banana|'` or `sed 's|[^/]\+|banana|'`.

Comment: @eigenfield: Yes I missed anchor (edited it now)

Comment: @KrischaOnarestlessday Negative, without the very important `{a, b}` constraint.